# populate form fields on select mysqli request row dropdown option

Tags: javascript, php, mysql, ajax, mysqli

please find attached a copy of my working example of retrieving addresses associated with the current user logged in.

The mysqli query is successfully printing the options for addresses saved to mysql database, associated with the session username. Addresses are also successfully saving on submit with the session username.

However, I would like to add functionality to populate the form fields with the selected option from the select class.

Form is for a checkout page where logged in users can select previously saved addresses to complete checkout process.

Any help greatly appreciated.

Table schema:

### [image]

Have updated username column to unique, now receiving duplicate key error.

Code updates as follows:

```
<div class="delivery-address-select">
    <select class="delivery-address-form-control" name="address">
        <option>Select An Address</option>
                            


$servername = "####";
$username = "####";
$password = "###";
$dbname = "####";

// Create connection
$conn = new mysqli($servername, $username, $password, $dbname);
// Check connection
if ($conn->connect_error) {
 die("Connection failed: " . $conn->connect_error);
 } 
$username = $_SESSION['username'];

$sql = "SELECT streetAddress, extendedAddress, locality, region, postalCode FROM addresses WHERE username='$username'";
$result = $conn->query($sql);

if ($result->num_rows > 0) {
  // output data of each row
 while ($row = $result->fetch_array()) {
if (!empty($_POST['address']) && $_POST['address'] == $row['id']) {
    $selected = 'selected="selected"';
} else {
    $selected = '';
}
echo '<option '.$selected.' value="'.$row["id"].'">'.$row["streetAddress"].', '.$row["extendedAddress"].', '.$row["locality"].', '.$row["region"].', '.$row["postalCode"].'</option>';
}
} else {
     echo "0 results";
}

$conn->close();?> 
                                
                            </select>
                    </div>
                              <form id="checkout" method="post" action="server.php">
                              <form id="saveAddress" method="post" action="insert.php">
                    <div class="add-an-address">
                        <div class="add-an-address-title">
                            <button id="add-new-address" class="add-new-address">Add new address</button>
                        </div>
                        <div class="add-an-address-container">
                            <div class="add-an-address-form">
                                    <div class="add-address-form-group">
                                        <div class="add-address-name-section">
                                        <input type="hidden" name="username" value="<?php echo $username; ?>" />
                                            <input type="text" name="firstName" class="delivery-address-form-control-first-name" placeholder="First Name" />
                                        </div>
                                        <div class="add-address-name-section">
                                            <input type="text" name="lastName" class="add-address-form-control" placeholder="Last Name" />
                                        </div>
                                    </div>
                                    <div class="add-address-form-group">
                                        <input type="text" name="company" class="add-address-form-control" placeholder="Business Name" />
                                    </div>
                                    <div class="add-address-form-group">
                                        <input type="number" name="phone" class="add-address-form-control" placeholder="Mobile Phone" />
                                    </div>
                                    <div class="add-address-form-group">
                                        <div class="street-left-section">
                                            <input type="text" name="streetAddress" class="delivery-address-form-control-first-name" placeholder="Street Address" />
                                        </div>
                                        <div class="street-right-section">
                                            <input type="text" name="extendedAddress" class="add-address-form-control" placeholder="Apt, Suite" />
                                        </div>
                                    </div>
                                    <div class="add-address-form-group">
                                        <div class="add-address-name-section">
                                            <input type="text" name="locality" class="delivery-address-form-control-first-name" placeholder="City" />
                                        </div>
                                        <div class="street-right-section">
                                            <input type="text" name="region" class="delivery-address-form-control-first-name" placeholder="State" />
                                        </div>
                                        <div class="street-right-section">
                                            <input type="text" name="postalCode" class="add-address-form-control" placeholder="Postal Code" />
                                        </div>
                                    </div>
                                    <div class="add-address-form-group">
                                        <input type="text" name="add-address-business-notes" class="add-address-form-control" placeholder="Notes" />
                                    </div>
                                    <div class="add-address-form-group-buttons">
                                        <button class="add-address-cancel" type="reset" id="add-address-cancel">Cancel</button>
                                        <button type="submit"  method="post" formaction="insert.php">Save</button>
                                    </div>
                                        </form>                     
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>`
```

Comment: Do you have a primary key in your addresses table?

Comment: thanks for quick response @KostasMitsarakis I have included print screen of table structure. No unique columns as it stands.

Comment: Check my answer and inform me if it was what you need.

Comment: @KostasMitsarakis Thank you so much! I will try out now

Answer (score 0):

You can use the following code. Note that you have to use prepared statements to avoid SQL Injection in your `SELECT` query. Also make sure that column `username` is `unique`.

Add a name attribute for your select box.

```
<select class="delivery-address-form-control" name="address">
```

Then in your while loop:

```
while ($row = $result->fetch_array()) {
    if (!empty($_POST['address']) && $_POST['address'] == $row['id']) {
        $selected = 'selected="selected"';
    } else {
        $selected = '';
    }
    echo '<option '.$selected.' value="'.$row["id"].'">'.$row["streetAddress"].', '.$row["extendedAddress"].', '.$row["locality"].', '.$row["region"].', '.$row["postalCode"].'</option>';
}
```

Comment: I tried it out, and made the column unique. When I tried to add a second address I get " Amyloula ERROR: Could not able to execute INSERT INTO addresses (username, streetAddress, extendedAddress, locality, region, postalCode) VALUES ('Amyloula', 'Fake Addresssss', 'Fake', 'Fake', 'Fake', '08002'). Duplicate entry 'Amyloula' for key 'username'"

Comment: Unique means that you cannot have two times the same value at a column row. So it's natural that the data not inserted.

Comment: Yes I understand that it's just I wondered if you had a recommendation work around as customers may need to save more than 1 address :) Thank you again for your help!

Comment: For this you have to make another table "customer" and in the "address" table you will have the foreign key "customer_id". Then you can have as many customers as you want in your "address" table.

Comment: Thanks very much for clarifying, I will change to a foreign key now! However, the address is not populating the fields, I will attach print screens now. The code I have live is included in the latest edit. It includes the while loop and select class :)

Comment: Please update your question only with the code you are currently use.

Comment: Sorry about that, I have updated the question to only include current code updates that you suggested :)

Comment: You use two <form> tags and your select is not inside the form. But i 'm pretty sure that the business logic is also wrong.